# Using imagick with php in files PSD

Tags: php, gd, imagick, psd

I would like to know if it is possible to get the name of the layer that the PSD has, using Imagick with PHP.

In this beginning I am already able to get the basic data of a layer, such as height, size, position x and position y (code below is an example).

```
for ($i = 0, $num_layers = $im->getNumberImages(); $i < $num_layers; ++$i) {
    $im->setImageIndex($i);         //this
    $im->setIteratorIndex($i);      //or this is kinda redundant
    $pagedata=$im->getImagePage();

    print("x,y: " . $pagedata["x"].", ".$pagedata["y"]."<br />\n");
    print("w,h: " . $pagedata["width"].", ".$pagedata["height"]."<br />\n");

    //export layer
    //$im->writeImage('layer_' . $i . '.png');
}
```

However I need to get the name of the layer too, attached is a print of the name that I need to get:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible.

```
// Load the PSD file
$psd = new Imagick($src);

// Export layers
foreach ($psd as $no => $layer) {

    // Skip the first layer 
    if (!$no) {
        continue;
    }

    // Get the layers positions and dimensions
    $imagePage = $layer->getImagePage();

    // Extract the next values ['x', y', 'width', 'height']
    extract($imagePage); 

    // Debug
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($imagePage);
    print '</pre>';

    // Get the name of this layer
    $imageProperties = $layer->getimageproperties();
    $label = $imageProperties['label'];

    // Do action by the name of the layer
    switch (strtolower($label)) {
        case 'layer-name':
            // Code...
            break;
        
        default:
            // Code...
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same thing more programmatically by using
`setIteratorIndex` to access the individual layers and adding them to an output image.

```
$imagick = new \Imagick(realpath("../images/LayerTest.psd"));

$output = new \Imagick();
$imagick->setIteratorIndex(1);
$output->addImage($imagick->getimage());

$imagick->setIteratorIndex(2);
$output->addImage($imagick->getimage());

$merged = @$output->flattenimages();
$merged->setImageFormat('jpg');
$merged->writeImage('test.jpg');
```

edit : fixed format

Comment: thanks for the answer, however i would like to know if i can get the name of the layer during the loop i am doing to get the dimensions and positions, in my case i need to have the name of the layer.

Comment: put the commands from the other link into PHP exec() commands and extract the array from the exec() and select the array element containing the names. see http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php.

Comment: https://legacy.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=23515

Comment: Thanks again. I understand, but I need the name of the layer, moreover I don't have permission on the server to execute the "exec" function, the Imagick api I saw that returns the file property, but in my case I need only the element property that make up the layers.
I saw in the link that you sent that the user was in the same situation as mine, the function of the Imagick "getProperty" returns the data only from the file, and does not return from the layer / frame.